# Timestamp of git clone, i.e. time when the repository has been cloned

Tags: git

With `git log` I can see the commit history. What I want to see is the timestamp when a repository has been cloned.

That is, after calling `git clone ...` I want to be able to see at what time that clone has been created. I'm talking about the clone, not about the origin.

In the git repository (i.e. the .git folder), there is a file logs/HEAD, and in that file, I see all the (local) commits (I assume of the current branch). And I also see the clone time:

```
00000000000 1a1a1a1a1a Author <email> 1699429282 +0100  clone: from https://...
2b2b22b2b2b 3c3c3c3c3c Author <email> 1699434977 +0100  commit: some message
....
```

Just to avoid wrong answers: As you can see in this (modified) example, the cloning has been logged by the git client!

How can I **retrieve that first line via some git command** (e.g., `git log`)?

(Initially, all cloned files have the timestamp when they were created during clone. But I cannot use that information, as files may have been changed.)

### Answer

This is the command line to see the date and time when a repository has been cloned:

```
git reflog show --date=iso
```

Other formats etc. are of course possible. The line above will output something like

```
....
5d8123df HEAD@{2023-11-07 15:12:03 +0100}: clone: from https://....git
```

(Kudos to Schwern, who pointed me to the git reflog command, which is (with option show) an alias for the git log command: `git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline`. So also kudos to knittl, who also remarks that the reflog is not stable, i.e. entries may be removed by certain actions)

Comment: I don't believe that information is logged anywhere by the git client.  I think you're on the right track by looking at files in the `.git` directory.  What OS are you using? in Linux, you can see creation time with the `stat` command...

Comment: It seems like you have your answer, read it from .git/logs/HEAD. This is normally read with `git-reflog`

Comment: You can self-answer your question. Don't include the answer in the question.

Comment: You are looking at the reflog. This log is going to be truncated so that it contains only entries younger than some certain time span (typically 90 days). When that time has passed, you will not see the time of the clone anymore in the HEAD reflog.

Answer (score 1):

`.git/logs/HEAD` is the [Git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). Even though each entry contains the timestamp when the reflog entry was written, this information is not accessible via regular Git commands¹.

But since the log is a regular text file, you could parse it yourself:

```
grep 'clone: from ' .git/logs/HEAD | cut -d'>' -f2- | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

Please note that the reflog is limited and entries will expire. You cannot rely on the "clone" entry to be in the log forever.

---

¹ https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats

Answer (score -1):

This is not logged anywhere by Git; Git only really concerns itself with when commits happen. You may be able to track it down with other logs on the host, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is similar to Bill Hunekes answer, isn't it? Well, the thing is: It is logged by Git, as I have shown in my initial question. My question is whether I can retrieve that via a command line call.